# Why is Doxygen so unfriendly to mobiles?

Tags: mobile, doxygen, documentation-generation

Doxygen seems to be the number one choice for code documentation in C++ (and many other languages) but every time I browse Doxygen generated doc from my phone, the site literally does not scroll, text is horribly small ...

How come ?

I come from python/sphinx, and sites like readthedocs.org manage perfectly mobile friendliness in the HTML generation (IMO), whereas the most popular documentation system around can't ? I must be missing something.

I tried looking around the interwebs for some HTML theme minimising problems, but no one even mentions the pain of trying to browse API references from a phone (yes, I do that :p)

Anyone experience the same problems or has a solution / workaround ?

Ps: Try [Google mobile friendliness test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) on doxygen API sites like [this intro to Doxygen, generated with Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html)

EDIT [2017] : Seems Doxygen is getting better, the link in question is now "fully compatible with mobile" according to the quoted google tool. Thanks to everyone in the community making things better !

Comment: Doxygen is, of course, an open source project. You could contribute your labor to make it more mobile-friendly,

Comment: I'm sorry if this question might seem insulting, but I'm genuinely wondering if I'm the only one to see this behaviour. I'd try to help if I could ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project on github called [doxygen-bootstrapped](https://github.com/Velron/doxygen-bootstrapped) using bootstrap for doxygen documentation,  making it much more mobile friendly. See [this demo](https://biogearsengine.com/documentation/index.html).

The demo is [marked as mobile-friendly](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbiogearsengine.com%2Fdocumentation%2Findex.html) by your link

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! It looks great.